# Exibir dados do banco quando clicar em linha da tabela

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Tenho uma tabela preenchida dinamicamente quando a pagina carrega com dados do banco, usando php, tudo funciona até então, porem preciso que ao click em uma linha na tabela ele exiba num painel lateral os dados da tabela mais alguns extras que estão no banco, como fazer isso ?

Já consigo obter o ID ao click na linha da tabela.

Comment: Coloque o código de ambas as coisas e como está a fazer no momento. Sem código fica dificil de ajudar

Comment: Imagino que não queira que a página sofra um refresh para carregar os dados, certo? Sendo assim você terá que trabalhar com requisições Ajax (é uma possibilidade) para atualizar uma div, que por sua vez seria justamente esse painel lateral que você citou. Resumindo: sua requisição Ajax vai chamar um script PHP que irá retornar os dados, seu jQuery pega estes dados e popula o painel lateral.

Answer (score 1):

O ideal é você apenas obter o ID de cada registro de sua tabela e fazer um Ajax para obter os outros resultados. Como você já está usando jQuery, você precisaria fazer um ajax em algum PHP que consulta esses valores e retorna.

```
function getInfoById(meu_id){
  $.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: 'getDados.php',
    data: {
      id: meu_id
    }
    success: function(dados){
      $("#resultados").html("Nome: " + dados.nome + ", idade: " + dados.idade);
    }
  });
}
```

Após receber o parâmetro do ID e fazer a consulta, você retorna o resultado em JSON usando [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-encode.php). Recebendo esse objeto de informações daquele unico registro, você já pode usa-lo para criar o modal ou exibir em outro lugar tranquilamente com jQuery, como no exemplo acima.

Segue exemplos de como trabalhar com Ajax e PHP juntos:

- [Receive PHP parameters with jQuery ajax post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11819791/receive-php-parameters-with-jquery-ajax-post)
- [Listando registro
  de Banco de Dados MySQL com AJAX, JSON e PHP](http://clubedosgeeks.com.br/programacao/listando-registro-de-banco-de-dados-mysql-com-ajax-json-e-php)